# Read complex values from properties.yml file in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://127.0.1:27017/FeteBird-Product
  kafka:
    bootstrapAddress: localhost:9092
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    consumer:
      key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            trusted:
              packages: '*'
```

How can I read all the values in spring boot, I know I can read by configuration as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties("demo")
public class Config {}
```

I don't know how to create a properties and access in other classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring")
public class ApplicationYmlConfiguration {
    private KafkaConfigurationYml kafka;

    public KafkaConfigurationYml getKafka() {
        return kafka;
    }

    public void setKafka(KafkaConfigurationYml kafka) {
        this.kafka = kafka;
    }
}


public class KafkaConfigurationYml {
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    public String getBootstrapAddress() {
        return bootstrapAddress;
    }

    public void setBootstrapAddress(String bootstrapAddress) {
        this.bootstrapAddress = bootstrapAddress;
    }
}
```

Read it anywhere

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {
    private ApplicationYmlConfiguration bootstrapAddress;

    public KafkaConfiguration(ApplicationYmlConfiguration bootstrapAddress) {
        this.bootstrapAddress = bootstrapAddress;
    }}
```